# Antlr undefined import in Antlrworks using composite grammars

Tags: antlr

I'm trying to use a composite grammar with Antlr 3.1 and Antlrworks 1.4.2. When I put the import statement in, it says 'undefined import'. I've tried a number of different combinations of lexer grammar and parser grammer but can't get it to generate the code. Am I missing something obvious? Am example is below.

```
grammar Tokens;

TOKEN   :   'token';
```

---

```
grammar Parser;
import Tokens;//gives undefined import error

rule    :   TOKEN+;
```

I'm referencing the documentation from

http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Composite+Grammars

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When separating lexer- and parser grammars, you need to explicitly define what type of grammar it is.

Try:

```
parser grammar Parser;
import Tokens;//gives undefined import error

rule    :   TOKEN+;
```

and:

```
lexer grammar Tokens;

TOKEN   :   'token';
```

Note that from a combined grammar file `Foo.g`, the lexer and parser get a `Parser` and `Lexer` prefix by default: `FooLexer.java` and `FooParser.java` respectively. But in "explicit" grammars, the name of the `.java` file is that of the grammar itself: `Parser.java` and `Tokens.java` in your case. You might want to watch out calling a class `Parser` since that is the name of ANTLR's base parser class:

http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/classorg_1_1antlr_1_1runtime_1_1_parser.html

Also watch out to place the `import` statement below the `options { ... }` section, but *before* any `tokens { ... }` you may have defined, otherwise you might get strange errors.

Answer (score 2):

Argghh It was something stupid. Antlrworks will underline the import and highlight all the tokens as undefined syntax errors but still allow you to generate the code if you try!

The reason it wasn't working the first time was the import was above the options as per Bart's suggestions.

Comment: :) yeah, ANTLRWorks is a great tool, but only for rather small, combined grammars.

Comment: Richard, note that the order of these section will likely disappear in ANTLR v4 (which still might take some time to come out though...).